# The content of a variable created in bash contains some invisible symbols, and these are not a new line

Tags: bash, curl, terminal

These 2 variables will have the same visible content

```
  x_sign1="aabbccdd_and_somthing_else"

  var1="...."
  [........]
  x_sign2=$(echo -n "${var1}${var2}${var3}" | shasum -a 256)
  echo $x_sign2

  ====> 
  aabbccdd_and_somthing_else -
```

Note the "-" in the end.

However, their lengths will be different. Even though the `x_sign2` doesn't contain a new line symbol. To ensure this:

```
  x_sign22=$(echo -n "${var1}${var2}${var3}" | shasum -a 256 | tr -d '\n')
```

But:

```
  echo ${#x_sign1}
  ====> 64
  And:
```

And:

```
  echo ${#x_sign2}

  ====> 67

  echo ${#x_sign22}

  ====> 67
```

The difference is 3 symbols. The visible content is identical.

Also, when I make a request via curl to a REST API which needs that value of a signature, `x_sign1` always succeeds, whereas `x_sign2` doesn't -- "wrong signature"

Why? How to fix that?

Comment: The only "invisible symbols" in there are two spaces and a dash, which are part of the output of shasum. You note the presence of a dash, why are you saying "the visible contents are identical"?

Comment: @Mat what's that dash, why is it there? why two spaces, how did those end up in the variable?   how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

Nonprintable characters could be a lot of things. If you want to remove *any* "nonprintable" characters, then tell `tr` that's what you want removed.

POSIX `tr` has a number of named character classes. For all printable characters, use `[:print:]`. To remove everything NOT in that set, `-d`elete the `-c`omplement of the set.

So, instead of

```
tr -d '\n'
```

use

```
tr -dc '[:print:]'
```

> IF THE PROBLEM is just the `' - '` on the end...

x_sign22="${x_sign22% -*}"

e.g.:

```
$: x="aabbccdd_and_somthing_else - "
$: echo "[$x]"
[aabbccdd_and_somthing_else - ]
$: x="${x% -*}"
$: echo "[$x]"
[aabbccdd_and_somthing_else]
```

Comment: Isn't the problem that their variables contain unwanted output of `shasum` (the space and dash)?

Comment: Ah, you're probably right. That's why I always echo my debugging vars with delimiters like `[$var]` or some such, lol